# Silverlight: How to change AxisLabelStyle in code behind?

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, charts

In the xaml file, we can change the AxisLabelStyle by doing this:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Orientation="X">
       <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
         <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                         <!--some code here-->
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
       </chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
    </chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis>
</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
```

My question is: how to add the AxisLabelStyle in code behind?

I know we can add DataPointStyle by doing this:

```
ColumnSeries CS = new ColumnSeries();
CS.DataPointStyle = Application.Current.Resources["ByteBlocksColumns"] as Style;
```

But apparently we cannot directly change the AxisLabelStyle like this because the AxisLabelStyle is inside a CategoryAxis.

Any one can help? Thanks!

Comment: But you can get the axis using something like this: _chart.ColumnSeries[0].IndependentAxis.AxisLabelStyle = ...; I haven't tested this code, so I don't know if this code can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this before, but in the IndependentAxis I cannot find AxisLabelStyle.

Comment: I've posted the answer that works in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your `xaml` a little.

```
    <charting:Chart>
        <charting:ColumnSeries x:Name="CS" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y">
            <charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" />
            </charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
        </charting:ColumnSeries> 
    </charting:Chart>
```

The xaml above can be written in c# so:

```
var CS = new ColumnSeries
         {
             ItemsSource = model.Items,
             IndependentValuePath = "X",
             DependentValuePath = "Y",
             IndependentAxis = new CategoryAxis { Orientation = AxisOrientation.X }
         };
```

And now in code-behind you can set the `AxisLabelStyle` property in this way:

```
var labelStyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "Category {0}"));

var axis = (CategoryAxis)CS.IndependentAxis;
axis.AxisLabelStyle = labelStyle;
```

Don't forget to cast the `IndependentAxis` property to a correct type, because by default it has the `IAxis` type which doesn't have a label style.

Comment: Hi, Vorrtex. In my application, I add the MyColumnSeries in run time. So when I fails to get the axis= (CategoryAxis)MyColumnSeries.IndependentAxis. It throws out a nullreference exception when I try to set axis's AxisLabelStyle.

Comment: @Mrainy When you create the ColumnSeries, set the IndependentAxis property on the next line. CS.IndependentAxis = new CategoryAxis{Orientation = AxisOrientation.X};

Comment: @Mrainy I've edited my answer, check the 2nd and 3rd blocks of code.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer inspires me a lot.