# Create style to rotate axis label in code behind

Tags: silverlight, charts, axis-labels

I need to create a style that rotates the x axis labels.
I've found this examples: [Easily rotate the axis labels of a Silverlight/WPF Toolkit chart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/03/06/turn-your-head-and-check-out-this-post-how-to-easily-rotate-the-axis-labels-of-a-silverlight-wpf-toolkit-chart.aspx) and [Rotating Text](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/170808/385146.aspx#385600) and [How to change AxisLabelStyle in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329710/silverlight-how-to-change-axislabelstyle-in-code-behind)

I need to do this in the code behind. So I've tried this:

```
var labelStyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
var rotate = new Setter(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, 270);
var setter = new Setter(AxisLabel.RenderTransformProperty, rotate);

labelStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
(xSerie.IndependentAxis as CategoryAxis).AxisLabelStyle = labelStyle;
```

I think I'm doing some mistake on the RenderTransformProperty.

What I have to do? Thanks!

Edit:
O just updated my code to:

```
var labelStyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));  
var setter = new Setter(AxisLabel.RenderTransformProperty, new RotateTransform(){Angle = -60, CenterX = 40, CenterY = 30});  
labelStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
```

And now it works fine!

Comment: What's happening and what do you expect to happen? I'd suspect the transform origin isn't what you think it it. Oh and don't hide your links behind shorteners, there's no shortage of characters available to you.

Comment: @ChirsF I want to rotate the labels 270 degrees, but with this code, nothing happens. I have used the shortener just to have a clean text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this from code, you should focus on manipulating the transform collection.

```
var group = new TransformGroup();
group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform() { Angle = 270 });
control.RenderTransform = group;
```

Alternatively, add your transform to an existing `RenderTransform`:

```
TransformGroup renderTransform = control.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
if (renderTransform != null)
{
    RotateTransform rotate = renderTransform.Children
         .FirstOrDefault(o => o is RotateTransform as RotateTransform 
    if(rotate == null)
    {
         rotate = new RotateTransform();
         renderTransform.Children.Add(rotate);
    }
    rotate.Angle = 270;
}
```

oh... You should also think about your `RenderTransformOrigin`:

```
control.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```